# How to convert the encoded file to another with c#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to convert file encoding from the default windows encoding to another specific encoding like "IBM864", and then save the file in the new encoding.

please any one can help me.

Comment: Try using `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the input file:

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(inputFilePath);
```

Write the content with the specified encoding:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(864); //864 is the codepage for IBM864-Arabic (864) 
File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath,content,enc);
```